# Eclipse não entra - gera log de erro de inicialização

Tags: eclipse, log

Após atualizar e instalar alguns componentes no Eclipse neon, ele não entra e passa a gerar o log abaixo:

```
         !SESSION 2016-08-21 18:42:45.858 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_102
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2016-08-21 18:43:08.264
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery. The reference is: Reference[name = RemoteServiceAdmin, interface = org.osgi.service.remoteserviceadmin.RemoteServiceAdmin, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..1, target = null, bind = bindRemoteServiceAdmin, unbind = unbindRemoteServiceAdmin]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1 0 2016-08-21 18:43:08.264
!MESSAGE Could not bind a reference of component org.eclipse.ecf.mgmt.rsa.discovery.ui.discovery. The reference is: Reference[name = IEndpointDescriptionLocator, interface = org.eclipse.ecf.osgi.services.remoteserviceadmin.IEndpointDescriptionLocator, policy = dynamic, cardinality = 0..1, target = null, bind = bindEndpointDescriptionLocator, unbind = unbindEndpointDescriptionLocator]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-08-21 18:43:24.093
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;Lorg/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/impl/XMLLoadImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the method's defining class, javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser, have different Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.getResource(ResourceHandler.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadResource(ResourceHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar a consertar isso?

Comment: Seria interessante você descrever melhor. Qual sistema operacional está usando? Quando começou acontecer o erro?

Comment: Utilizo Windows 10 pro - AMD A4 7300 4.0GHz 8GB Ram. Tive esse problema após instalar os suportes para outras linguagens.

Comment: Já tentou desinstalar novamente "os suportes" para ver se volta ao normal?

Comment: Então... O eclipse nem entra, da erro na tela de inicialização por conta dos plugins instalados.

Comment: Vai lá na pasta do seu eclipse > plugins e procure o plugin que você instalou. Aí você apaga ela.